Issues with NextAuth: Login Works Locally but Not in Production
I'm experiencing an issue with integrating NextAuth in my Next.js project. Locally, the login with Google works perfectly, but when I deploy the application to production, the login fails to connect. The same thing happens when I try to log in with email and password: even with the correct credentials, the connection fails.
Here’s the setup I’m using:
Frontend: Next.js with NextAuth for authentication
Backend: Strapi
I have correctly configured the environment variables, and if I run the frontend locally while connecting to the online Strapi server, everything works as expected. However, when both the frontend and backend are in production, the connection between them no longer works.
Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this issue?
I have already checked the following:
The environment variables for production are set correctly.
The callback URL domain is correctly configured in the Google project and NextAuth settings.
The Strapi APIs are accessible and work correctly in production when queried manually.
This is my next/auth config:
    import { StrapiErrorT } from '@/types/strapi/StrapiError';
import { StrapiLoginResponseT } from '@/types/strapi/User';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import { signIn } from '../app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/strapi-connector';

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID ?? '',
      clientSecret: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET ?? '',
    }),
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'e-mail',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'text' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials) return null;

        try {
          const { user, jwt } = await signIn({
            email: credentials.email,
            password: credentials.password,
          });

          // Restituisci il token JWT e i dati utente
          return { ...user, jwt };
        } catch (error) {
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (
        account &&
        account.provider === 'google' &&
        profile &&
        'email_verified' in profile &&
        !profile.email_verified
      ) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },

    async jwt({ token, account, user }) {
      if (account && account.provider === 'google') {
        try {
          const strapiResponse = await fetch(
            `${process.env.STRAPI_URL}/api/auth/${account.provider}/callback?access_token=${account.access_token}`,
            { cache: 'no-cache' }
          );
          if (!strapiResponse.ok) {
            const strapiError: StrapiErrorT = await strapiResponse.json();
            throw new Error(strapiError.error.message);
          }
          const strapiLoginResponse: StrapiLoginResponseT = await strapiResponse.json();
          token.strapiToken = strapiLoginResponse.jwt;
          token.strapiUserId = strapiLoginResponse.user.id;
          token.provider = account.provider;
          token.blocked = strapiLoginResponse.user.blocked;
        } catch (error) {
          throw error;
        }
      }

      if (account && account.provider === 'local') {
        token.strapiToken = user.jwt;
        token.strapiUserId = user.id;
        token.provider = 'local';
        token.blocked = user.blocked;
      }

      return token;
    },

    async session({ token, session }) {
      session.strapiToken = token.strapiToken;
      session.provider = token.provider;
      session.user = {
       ...session.user,
        strapiUserId: token.strapiUserId,
        blocked: token.blocked,
      };
      return session;
    }
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    newUser: '/auth/signup',
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
  theme: {
    colorScheme: 'light',
    brandColor: '',
    logo: '/MagazzinoBlackLogo.png',
    buttonText: '',
  },
};

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!
